# Bind handlers on page load with .each() and adopt them with jQuery .clone(true,true)

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone, each

To prepare dropdown elements and their behavior i bind click event handlers to show/hide the appropriate shallow divs (e.g. the dropdown menu lists) with jQuery .each().

```
// Excerpt, this is just for debugging purpose, s. below also

$('.m-dropdown-select__trigger').each(function() {

    var triggerElem = $(this);

    triggerElem.on('click', function(e) {
        if(e) e.stopPropagation();
        if(e) e.preventDefault();
        if(triggerElem.hasClass('is-open')) {
            // debug if we are in the original or cloned object
            alert('hide this, ' + triggerElem.closest('dl').attr('id') + ', parent: ' + triggerElem.parents('.m-form-elements--accompanied__item').attr('id'));
            triggerElem.removeClass('is-open');
        } else {
            // debug if we are in the original or cloned object
            alert('show this, ' + triggerElem.closest('dl').attr('id') + ', parent: ' + triggerElem.parents('.m-form-elements--accompanied__item').attr('id'));
            triggerElem.addClass('is-open');
        }
    });
});
```

When i deep copy (with .clone(true, true)) a div which comprises one of those dropdowns, the event handler are **not** bound to the **dropdown within the cloned div** but on the **original object**.

E.g. i have a link somewhere in the page which copies additional accompanies form inputs (and a dropdown for salutation) and insert them after the last item.

```
// Clone first hardcoded container, adapt some attributes and insert it

var accompaniesCount = 2;

$('.js-add-accompanies').on('click', function(e) {
    if(e) e.preventDefault();

    var count = accompaniesCount++;

    // Grap the first (hardcoded) item and copy it
    var cont = $('#accompanied-item-1').clone(true, true);

    // change clone attributes
    cont.attr('id', 'accompanied-item-' + count );
    cont.find('.m-form-elements--accompanied__heading span').text(count);
    cont.find('.m-dropdown-select__select')
        .attr('id', function(index, attr) {
                return attr.replace(1, count);
            })
        .attr('name', function(index, attr) {
                return attr.replace(1, count);
            })
    cont.find('.m-dropdown-select__definitionlist')
        .attr('id', function(index, attr) {
                return attr.replace(1, count);
            })
    cont.find('input').val('');

    cont.insertAfter($('[id^=accompanied-item-]:last'));

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/felic/L98jzkko/18/

Info for the fiddle example: Click on "Anrede" twice to get debugged output. Then click on "Add accompanies" and toggle "Anrede" there. Parent is always the first entry (e.g. the original object).

What i am missing here? Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are dealing with dynamic elements, so the way to register event handlers is to use event delegation

```
$(document).on('click', '.m-dropdown-select__trigger', function(e) {
    var triggerElem = $(this);
    if(e) e.stopPropagation();
    if(e) e.preventDefault();
    if(triggerElem.hasClass('is-open')) {
        // debug if we are in the original or cloned object
        alert('hide this, ' + triggerElem.closest('dl').attr('id') + ', parent: ' + triggerElem.parents('.m-form-elements--accompanied__item').attr('id'));
        triggerElem.removeClass('is-open');
    } else {
        // debug if we are in the original or cloned object
        alert('show this, ' + triggerElem.closest('dl').attr('id') + ', parent: ' + triggerElem.parents('.m-form-elements--accompanied__item').attr('id'));
        triggerElem.addClass('is-open');
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/1u2h9k9p/)

Comment: Thx a lot for your answer. You hit the spot. Unfortunately the event binding of the triggerElem is a part of a more complex (.each()) loop to address showing/hiding dropdowns in conjunction to related dropdowns on page (i left this out in the demo to straighten it up a bit). But maybe you get me on the right track and should think about this approach again. I will fiddle around with it.

Comment: Just did it. Binding the event handler to $(document) explicitly did the job. Great. Thx a lot.